# onClickListener on Whole Recylcerview doesn't work

Tags: android

In xml,

```
        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/itemRecyclerview"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            android:paddingTop="20dp"
            android:paddingBottom="20dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="true"/>
```

In `onCreateView` in `Fragement`,

```
    binding.apply {
        itemRecyclerview.setOnClickListener {
            NavigateWithItemname(itemname)
            Log.i("click","click") //doesn't work
        }
    }
```

`setOnClickListener` on whole `RecylcerView` doesn't work. ( I don't see click Log in `logcat` )

I don't know why...

Comment: why do you want to click on the whole recycleView? don't you want to get a click on each item?

Comment: @Avital this `Recyclerview` shows only 3 items, and If user click an this `Recylcerview` , I wanna let user navigate into `ReviewFragment` which shows full items.

Comment: but don't you want to show a different item each click? anyway, you can set onClickListener to every item, and navigate to ReviewFragment

Comment: @Avital OK, I think I should make another adapter for it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use onClickListener on ItemView this will help to navigate through position wise:

```
holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(v -> {
       if(position==0){
            openFragmentA();
       }else if(position == 1){
            openFragmentB();
    }else{  
            openFragmentC();
    }
    
    });
```